# Why can't I fetch a single tweet using the twitter API v2

Tags: api, twitter, postman

I am using postman to fetch a single tweet using the Twitter API v2 collection and I am following the instructions located on Twitter about Getting Started with Postman at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/postman-getting-started. I have created a Twitter developer account and created a Twitter project and app and I have all the relevant keys and tokens but I still cannot fetch a single tweet.

```
consumer_key Mpe1zQ8fiKzDID5bH05N5CJaN
consumer_secret 6xFVjRKptcRCzqejHYsyr9OD04kHry9bjvLHFrRyyKvYFDSg7T
access_token 1281893389177442305-rQPFU4LsWptVXuF8x39qPnhS7R4nNe
token_secret qxbmuhI4dYbrxeZfD7bpKjRSBoGtWA46PrSsRravHzQqP
bearer_token AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABMteAEAAAAA5HAEzHzCza9Uz7txmF7MadTuc4Q%3DkXpfuAn8Lbi9wRnzBSCUFXiZEjuypSru3mPUHoEvSJsV5PR9V9

id 1541685424221028353
```

But when I click Send, I get back the following;

```
{
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "type": "about:blank",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the headers as expected? Is the `Content-Type` correct?

Comment: @BartBarnard It doesn't mention anything about sending headers in the link above.

Comment: All of those API values are meant to be secrets - I suggest you go to your application dashboard and regenerate all of them immediately.

Comment: @AndyPiper I'm not bothered because I can just delete the app when I've got this working.